# EmbeddedMongo starting on a random port every time?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I am using [Flapdoodle's Embedded Mongo](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo) to run integration tests on my Spring Boot App.

I have test like the following:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
class IntegrationTests {

@BeforeAll
    static void setup() throws Exception {
        String ip = "localhost";
        int port = 65000;

        IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
                .net(new Net(ip, port, Network.localhostIsIPv6())).build();

        MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
        mongodExecutable = starter.prepare(mongodConfig);
        mongodExecutable.start();

        mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(String.format(CONNECTION_STRING, ip, port)), "test");

}
```

But every time the MongoDB server is started on a random port:

```
[2021-03-16T01:41:26.026Z] [com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger] [main] [71] [INFO ] Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:2}] to localhost:55359
```

**I have tried using different values for the port but none of them work.**

**Why is my configuration not being respected ?**

Let me know if any other info is required from my side.

Comment: What do you have in CONNECTION_STRING ?

Comment: @PhilippeSimo `mongodb://localhost:55172`

Comment: I mean the initial value of CONNECTION_STRING : the template. As you are using string.format, what's the templare

Comment: @PhilippeSimo Initial Value is `mongodb://%s:%d`

Comment: So you should get `mongodb://localhost:65000` instead of  `mongodb://localhost:55172` as you mentioned. I'll try to reproduce your issue and let you know

Comment: @PhilippeSimo The connection string is getting set properly but for some reason it tries to connect to a different port.

Answer (score 0):

Just exclude the default loaded AutoConfiguration class:

```
@DataMongoTest(excludeAutoConfiguration = EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class)
class IntegrationTests { ... }
```

By the way, I used the slice test annotation `@DataMongoTest` instead of `@SpringBootTest` in order to bootstrap only what you need (MongoDB-related beans) for the tests.